# java-recursively finding a specific path in array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

i would like to know to can i calculate 2 specific paths in a given array.

1. how can i return the shortest (or longest) path from [0][0] to [m][n]? i manage to progress through the array recursively but i don't know how i can "save" the paths and check which one is smaller to return.

   2. this one's a bit more specific and complicated- each cell has an integer (pos/neg), and valid progressions in the array are n+1 or m+1. i would like to add each cell's value and return the lowest possible number that will guarantee a positive sum of all the cells from [0][0] to [n][m]. for example, if the lowest sum of path x is -3, the number returned will be 4 (4-3=1).

the 2nd request is a question i've been stuck at for quite a while but i've seen other questions regarding using and calculating stuff with the values in those arrays.

Comment: Please can you add what you tried so far.

Comment: You should ask a second question for your second request and remove it here.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't been very descriptive I'll just try to explain the basic concept as well as I can.

1) Check if the current coordinate has reached a goal, return the current sum. This is the base case.

2) Check if the current steps taken exceeds the maximum number of steps needed to prevent infinite reccurrsion. This is the fail case, necessary when using breadth first search.

3) Check if the next desired position you are walking to is within the grid, and hasn't been visited before. Mark it as visited and save the sum from that path. When you get back, mark that position as not visited and try the next move available... and so on for all possible directions.

4) When all possible paths have been tried compare their results to see which was the smallest one and return that as a solution.

Example using depth first recurssion:

```
   public void solve(int[][] a, boolean[][] visited, int sum, int steps, int x, int y, int xMax, int yMax) {
            if (isSolved(x, y)) { // Base case - solved
                return sum;
            }
            if (steps > MAX_STEPS) {
                return Integer.MAX_VALUE; // Return invalid if the algorithm exceeds maximum steps to prevent unlimited seek time
            }

            int[] path = new int[NUM_PATHS]; // An array holding the calculated paths for all possible options. Should
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PATHS; i++) {
                path[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // Should be set to fail case as default.
            }

            if (canReach(x + 1, y) && !visited[y][x +1]) {
                visited[y][x + 1] = true;
                path[0] = solve(a, visited, sum + a[y][x + 1] steps + 1, x + 1, y, xMax, yMax);
                visited[y][x + 1] false;
            } 
            if (canReach(x - 1, y) && !visited[y][x - 1]) {
               ...
            }
            ... etc
            // Finding the best solution
            min = path[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < path.length; i++) {
                if (path[i] < min) 
                    min = path[i]; 
            }
            return min;
       }
```

With dynamic programming you can optimize your algorithm to disregard paths that are worse than the previously found best, thus shortening the recursions needed.

Also if you want to save the path taken you do that through an ArrayList and add/remove it as you do when you mark a node as visited.